# Laravel popup with jQuery/jQuery UI

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I was wondering, is it possible to use jquery or jquery ui on a laravel popup window?
More details:
I'm making a website on which you have to sign in to enter. If you forget your pass you click forgot password (captain obvious).
When i enter my e-mail, i want to make a popup sub-window where you are informed that an email with your code has been sent. So, is it possible to use jquery/jquery ui with laravel to make a cool popup animation. If it's possible, do you perhaps have a link that I can visit to see how it works?
Much obliged

Comment: Laravel is just php, which spits out just html, so I don't see why you couldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sweetalert](http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/) package in your laravel